# Apache Camel: How to transmit exceptions over a SEDA endpoint?

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

When I sent messages in a Camel Context Component to its endpoint, I have to wait for a response message with acknowledgement. If no response is received within timeout time, an exception shall be thrown back to the camel route.

I tried to implement it the following way:
I used a multicast to generate a timeout response while the original message is sent to the endpoint. The timeout response is delayed and if no response is received after this timeout, a timeout exception shall be thrown back on the route.

So I have the following route:

```
private final String internalRespUri = "direct:internal_resp";
private final String internalRespTimeout = "seda:internaltimeout";

@Override
public void configure() {
    SendController send_controller = new SendController();
    TimeoutResponse resp = new TimeoutResponse();

    from(Endpoints.MESSAGE_IN.direct())
                    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
                    .routeId(Endpoints.MESSAGE_IN.atsm())
                    .log("Incoming message at segment in")
                    .process(send_controller)
                    .log("Message after send controller")
                    .multicast().parallelProcessing()
                    .log("After wiretap")
                    .to(internalRespTimeout, Endpoints.SEGMENT_OUT.direct());
    from(internalRespTimeout)
                    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
                    .routeId(internalRespTimeout)
                    .log("begin response route")
                    .log("timeout response route")
                    .process(resp)
                    .log("modify message to response")
                    .delay(1000)
                    .log("after delay")
                    .to(internalRespUri);
    from(Endpoints.SEGMENT_IN.seda())
                    .routeId(Endpoints.SEGMENT_IN.atsm())
                    .to(internalRespUri);
    from(internalRespUri)
                    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
                    .routeId(internalRespUri)
                    .log("after response gathering point")
                    .choice()
                    .when(header(HeaderKeys.TYPE.key()).isEqualTo(UserMessageType.RESP.toString()))
                    .log("process responses")
                    .process(send_controller)
                    .otherwise()
                    .log("no response")
                    .to(Endpoints.MESSAGE_OUT.direct());
}
```

The problem is that the exception thrown in the SendController is not propagated over the SEDA endpoint internalRespTimeout.
If I use a direct endpoint instead it works, but then I have another problem:
The delay blocks the route while a received response message from endpoint  Endpoints.SEGMENT_IN.seda() may not be transmitted.

Are SEDA endpoint generally not able to propagate exceptions?
How can I achieve a solution to my problem?

Thanks,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea:

Instead of throwing an exception, I possibly could use transactions for timeout.

Could this work?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently not aware of a way to propagate and exception back over a SEDA endpoint in camel.  The way the error handling works is based on channels between endpoints.  When you use a SEDA endpoint the code will keep processing and not wait for the code since it will keep processing.  I am having a bit of trouble understanding what you would like to accomplish, but I will list some similar alternatives you might be able to use.

-The first is to use a route level error handler in your SEDA based route and store the exception using a unique Id that you can lookup later.

-The second is to pass the data into a Java Bean where you have full control of what you are doing and could even consider something like using a Guava's Futures to run the code asynchronously while doing other tasks.

If you can explain what you are trying to accomplish a bit better I might be able to make a clearer suggestion.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to implement an internal protocol of my company in a Camel Context Component to be used as library in different applications. Then it could be used as a Blackbox with 4 Endpoints.

Comment: When messages are to be packed with the protocol, each message is sent to the endpoint Endpoints.MESSAGE_IN.direct(). In the context component the protocol sppplits the message in segments and send it out via Endpoints.SEGMENT_OUT.direct(). When the segments are received from the counterpart it sends back response messages with status codes.via Endpoints.SEGMENT_IN.direct().
Then I interpret the status codes and the timeout behaviour if no response is received from counterpart.

Comment: The problem is, how to send back an exception, if no or an error response is received? IT should be propagated back on the route to the caller of endpoint Endpoints.MESSAGE_IN.direct(). As the original message is already sent, camel does not know how to react on an exception and where to propagate it.